# Does a detached thread terminate if its owning class destructs

Tags: multithreading, c++11

Suppose I have a class like this

```
class foo
{
  void foo() 
  {
     std::thread t(std::bind(&foo::doSomething,this));
     t.detach();
  }

  void doSomething()
  {
     while(true)
     {
       //Does some stuff here
     }
  }
};
```

My question is in the above scenario if foo class destructs will the detached thread terminate as well ? From my current observation it seems like it does exit.Also I believe the reason for this is because since the thread has access to the member variables of the instance and once the destructor is called those member variables are no longer present so it makes sense to conclude that the thread exits too. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.Also what if the thread does not access member variables will it still exit if the class destructs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't necessarily exit. If it access members of the `foo` that started it after that `foo` is destroyed, you have undefined behaviour. That **may** have the symptoms of `doSomething` exiting and the thread ceasing naturally, or anything else.

Comment: what if it does not access any member variables ? Will it continue even after class is destructed ?

Comment: Yes. There is no spooky action-at-a-distance that stops it